# Trying to generate swagger client code using maven for java

Tags: java, maven, swagger, pom.xml

I am trying to generate swagger code according to my yaml file without success, this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>rail_project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>rail_project</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>4.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
      <version>8.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>4.4.6</version>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.3.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.garethevans.plugin</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <inputSpec>src/main/resources/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

when I am running the following command: `mvn clean compile` I would expect to see the generated swagger client code but without success (no code was generated), I was following this link https://github.com/garethjevans/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin for steps how to generate.
What am I missing?

Comment: FYI. Many swagger codegen contributors are now working on OpenAPI Generator instead, which comes with an official [maven plug-in](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md). Not sure if it works better in your use cases but still worth mentioning.

Comment: I'm sorry. Sometimes I forget to switch the language. Is your swagger.yaml exactly named so and is it located at src/main/resources ? Did you try to run the maven compile step in Debug mode (-X command line flag)? That may print out some usefull information, if something goes wrong.